# Transform objects pointfree style with Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

Given the function below, how do I convert it to point-free style? Would be nice to use Ramda's `prop` and `path` and skip the data argument, but I just can't figure out the proper syntax.

```
const mapToOtherFormat = (data) => (
    {
        'Name': data.Name
        'Email': data.User.Email,
        'Foo': data.Foo[0].Bar
    });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option would be to make use of [`R.applySpec`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec), which creates a new function that builds objects by applying the functions at each key of the supplied "spec" against the given arguments of the resulting function.

```js
const mapToOtherFormat = R.applySpec({
  Name: R.prop('Name'),
  Email: R.path(['User', 'Email']),
  Foo: R.path(['Foo', 0, 'Bar'])
})

const result = mapToOtherFormat({
  Name: 'Bob',
  User: { Email: 'bob@example.com' },
  Foo: [{ Bar: 'moo' }, { Bar: 'baa' }]
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt:

```
const mapToOtherFormat = R.converge(
    (...list) => R.pipe(...list)({}),
    [
      R.pipe(R.view(R.lensProp('Name')), R.set(R.lensProp('Name'))),
      R.pipe(R.view(R.compose(R.lensProp('User'), R.lensProp('Email'))), R.set(R.lensProp('Email'))),
      R.pipe(R.view(R.compose(R.lensProp('Foo'), R.lensIndex(0), R.lensProp('Bar'))), R.set(R.lensProp('Foo')))
    ]
  )

const obj = {Name: 'name', User: {Email: 'email'}, Foo: [{Bar: 2}]}
mapToOtherFormat(obj)
```

[Ramda console](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?code=const%20mapToOtherFormat%20%3D%20R.converge%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28...list%29%20%3D%3E%20R.pipe%28...list%29%28%7B%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pipe%28R.view%28R.lensProp%28%27Name%27%29%29%2C%20R.set%28R.lensProp%28%27Name%27%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pipe%28R.view%28R.compose%28R.lensProp%28%27User%27%29%2C%20R.lensProp%28%27Email%27%29%29%29%2C%20R.set%28R.lensProp%28%27Email%27%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pipe%28R.view%28R.compose%28R.lensProp%28%27Foo%27%29%2C%20R.lensIndex%280%29%2C%20R.lensProp%28%27Bar%27%29%29%29%2C%20R.set%28R.lensProp%28%27Foo%27%29%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%29%0A%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7BName%3A%20%27name%27%2C%20User%3A%20%7BEmail%3A%20%27email%27%7D%2C%20Foo%3A%20%5B%7BBar%3A%202%7D%5D%7D%0AmapToOtherFormat%28obj%29%0A)

[Edit]
We can make it completely point-free:

```
const mapToOtherFormat = R.converge(
    R.pipe(R.pipe, R.flip(R.call)({})),
    [
      R.pipe(R.view(R.lensProp('Name')), R.set(R.lensProp('Name'))),
      R.pipe(R.view(R.compose(R.lensProp('User'), R.lensProp('Email'))), R.set(R.lensProp('Email'))),
      R.pipe(R.view(R.compose(R.lensProp('Foo'), R.lensIndex(0), R.lensProp('Bar'))), R.set(R.lensProp('Foo')))
    ]
  )
```

[Ramda console](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?code=const%20mapToOtherFormat%20%3D%20R.converge%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.pipe%28R.pipe%2C%20R.flip%28R.call%29%28%7B%7D%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pipe%28R.view%28R.lensProp%28%27Name%27%29%29%2C%20R.set%28R.lensProp%28%27Name%27%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pipe%28R.view%28R.compose%28R.lensProp%28%27User%27%29%2C%20R.lensProp%28%27Email%27%29%29%29%2C%20R.set%28R.lensProp%28%27Email%27%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pipe%28R.view%28R.compose%28R.lensProp%28%27Foo%27%29%2C%20R.lensIndex%280%29%2C%20R.lensProp%28%27Bar%27%29%29%29%2C%20R.set%28R.lensProp%28%27Foo%27%29%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%29%0A%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7BName%3A%20%27name%27%2C%20User%3A%20%7BEmail%3A%20%27email%27%7D%2C%20Foo%3A%20%5B%7BBar%3A%202%7D%5D%7D%0AmapToOtherFormat%28obj%29%0A)